# How could I create a self-updating django field that stores all instances of a given Model?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class Cow (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="brown")
```

On our farm we have many cows. Typically, the farmer takes cows to the vet in defined batch:

```
class Cow_Batch(models.Model):
    batch_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cows = models.ManyToManyField(Cow)
```

In our admin, we can create a Cow_Batch, allowing our farmer to easily take Daisy and Debbie (two sisters with a similar medical condition) to the vet together.

I'd like to be able to have 'all' as a Cow_Batch. That's easy enough to populate myself, but I'd like the contents of 'all' to update automatically when new cows are added to the herd. The end purpose is to be able to use:

```
class Vet_Visit(models.Model):
    cows_brought_to_vet = models.ForeignKey(Cow_Batch)
```

and have 'all' as a valid possibility, among others.

Comment: In this particular context, I'm not sure your 'all' batch makes sense. If I make a vet visit today with all of my 6 cows, and then come back to review my records next week, I expect this visit to show 6 cows, and not the 2 new ones I may have bought between now and then.

Comment: Dokkaebi - you're absolutely right, and in this particular model something else would probably be better. I think the 'all' case is fine for the actual project that this abstracted, but thank you for raising the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of [django post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) for `Cow` model. In the signal handler when new `Cow` is added, you add it to *all* `Cow_Batch`.

[Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)